# Remove empty span tags if it is in with in paragraph tags using Regex

Tags: c#

Need to remove `<span style="color:#000000;"/>` tag when `<span>` tag is empty

```
<html>
   <body>       
      <p left-margin="0" style="margin:0 0 0 0;text-align:Left;font-style:italic;"><span style="color:#000000;"/></p>
      <p>Newly <span style="font-weight:bold;">Created</span> this document...</p>
      <p />
      <p>Regards,</p>
      <p>Dhanush.</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Already we are using below regEx for removing unwanted XML

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
{
    var xmlPattern = "[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\xD7FF\xE000-\xFFFD\x10000-\x10FFFF]";
    return Regex.Replace(text, xmlPattern, string.Empty);
}
```

I need to final result like below

```
<html>
   <body>       
      <p left-margin="0" style="margin:0 0 0 0;text-align:Left;font-style:italic;">
      <p>Newly <span style="font-weight:bold;">Created</span> this document...</p>
      <p />
      <p>Regards,</p>
      <p>Dhanush.</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Regex for any XML parsing!

Using `XDocument` will suffice here:

```
var html = XDocument.Parse(htmlString);
var spanElements = html.Descendants("span").ToList(); 
for (int i = spanElements.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    if (spanElements[i].Value == "") spanElements[i].Remove();
```

Comment: Input are below but it will not remove empty span tag.                                           
string html ='<html>
   <body>
      <p left-margin="0" style="margin:0 0 11 0;text-align:Left;">Hi</p>
      <p left-margin="0" style="margin:0 0 11 0;text-align:Left;font-style:italic;">
         <span style="font-style:normal;" />
      </p>
      <p left-margin="0" style="margin:0 0 11 0;text-align:Left;">
         <span style="font-style:italic;" />
         Kodi
      </p>
   </body>
</html>'

Comment: Turczyn thanks for your reply i am trying to load string value instead of path it throwing error. inputs are,   string html ='<html> <body> <p left-margin="0" style="margin:0 0 11 0;text-align:Left;">Hi</p> <p left-margin="0" style="margin:0 0 11 0;text-align:Left;font-style:italic;"> <span style="font-style:normal;" /> </p> <p left-margin="0" style="margin:0 0 11 0;text-align:Left;"> <span style="font-style:italic;" /> Kodi </p> </body> </html>'

Comment: @DhanushKodi Because you can't pass text there, you have to pass PATH to the file contaning HTML.

Comment: Is it possible to other way because we have used code previously like below,  we cant change existing code just want to remove empty span tag from existing html string,                                                                                                                
string html = Utilities.GetHtmlContent(richText).RemoveInvalidXmlCharacters();
                    canLoadContent = false;
                    Html = html;

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use `HtmlAgilityPack` instead of `Regex`

Use this `Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack -Version 1.11.4` command in the package manager console to install nuget package for `HtmlAgilityPack`

**Code:**

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"Path to html file");

if (doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span") != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span"))
    {
        var attributes = node.Attributes;

        foreach (var item in attributes)
        {
            if (item.Name.Equals("style") && item.Value.Contains("color:#000000;"))
            {
                node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
            }
        }
    }
}

string html = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

**Output:** (From Debugger)

[image]